# meaning of the phrase "be better then one can say"?

Tags: meaning

It is from [Crash Course World History](https://youtu.be/T_sGTspaF4Y). It is at around 11 minute and 30 second. Here is the context:

> Benin's economy has grown in each of the past 12 years, which is better then Europe and or the US can say.

Does that mean that Europe or the US didn't think that Benin's economy would prove to have economy growth?

Comment: can say *about themselves*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence the sentence is saying:

> Benin's economy has grown in each of the past 12 years, which is better than the economic growth in either Europe or the US.

The idiom is usually presented in the form:

> A has done something great, which is more than you can say for B.

Generally, the comparison between A and B is set up in such a way that the average person would expect B to be better than A, but the sentence reveals that the opposite is true instead.

For example:

> I left school at 15 but I now earn more than a million dollars a year, which is more than my brother with three university degrees can say.